# How to whitelist IP Address in IPBan Application?

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall

I have a Windows server with IPBan(https://github.com/DigitalRuby/IPBan). sometimes its blocks my local system IP.

How can I whitelist the IP Addresses in the IPBan Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the comma separated addresses to the appsettings\Whitelist element in ipban.config.

https://github.com/DigitalRuby/IPBan/wiki/Configuration/4cc483bd4b7179fa43d86475d2061ca2f631bc7f

https://github.com/DigitalRuby/IPBan/blob/master/IPBanCore/ipban.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>

    <!--
    Comma separated list of ip addresses, cidr masks, urls or dns names that are never banned. Whitelist takes precedence over blacklist.
    If you use a url, the response should be text and newline delimited, example: https://uptimerobot.com/inc/files/ips/IPv4andIPv6.txt.
    For urls, ? char is not allowed, so if you need a query string, you must create a non ? url and have it 302 redirect to the new url with a ? in it.
    Ips in this list are added to a whitelist firewall rule and will always be allowed.
    -->
    <add key="Whitelist" value=""/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```